# How to call struct's custom constructor with all arguments having default values?

Tags: d

Suppose I have the following struct:

```
import std.stdio;
struct A
{
    this (int arg = 1) {
        writeln("Correct constructor");
    }

    this(); 
}
```

How to use the default value of the constructor?

The

```
void main()
{
            A a = A();
}
```

...produces `Error: constructor app.A.this is not callable because it is annotated with @disable`. If I remove `@disable` attribute from default constructor, I would not get my own constructor executed.

And, why structs aren't allowed to have custom default constructor anyway?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the  deal is with struct ctors, but you could cheat and try overloading static opCall:

```
import std.stdio;
struct A {
    static auto opCall() {
        writeln("Correct constructor");
        auto a = typeof(this).init;
        return a;
    };
};

void main() {
    A a = A();
};
```

Comment: That appears to be working. How much cheating it is? Should I expect any side-effects? E.g. I noticed, that when I replace the line in main with `A a = A.init` the static opCall doesn't get called, but that is no issue with me.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski: my main concern would be that `A.__ctor` doesn't exist with this approach, which could interfere with some introspection techniques. I honestly don't have much experience with `static opCall`, but I suspect it will work fine for most use-cases.

Comment: Also, as you noted, `.init` will never call a function, as it compiles to a simple `mov` or `rep movs` (x86) to write the default field values.

Answer (score 1):

You should not implement the default struct constructor (here is why: [Why can I not implement default constructors for structs in D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648273/why-can-i-not-implement-default-constructors-for-structs-in-d)).

Remove the `this();` line in your code. You do not need it.

If you want some specific value to be your default one, just make it at module level and use it throughout your application. Like in the following example:

```
import std.stdio;

struct A {
  int a;
  int b;

  this (int arg = 1) {
     a = arg;
     // writeln("Correct constructor");
  }

}

immutable(A) defA = A(5);

void main() {
  A a1 = A(2);
  writeln(a1); // output: A(2, 0)

  // Or, init all to defaults
  A a2 = A.init;
  writeln(a2); // output: A(0, 0)
  A a3 = A();  // same as A.init, as you can see
  writeln(a3); // output: A(0, 0)

  A a4 = defA; // Let's use our "default" value
  a4.b = 10;
  writeln(a4); // output: A(5, 10)
}
```

Comment: Nope. It calls the "Correct construcor" only once, on second invocation (`A a2 = A(2)`). The first one calls the default constructor, that initializes everything with zeroes and never executes custom code.

Comment: The first one is the struct initialiser. I did not say it will execute the constructor with the default parameter. The second one does. I will edit my post to avoid this misunderstanding.